# Where ID in set of parameters and no where else ( 1 Row of data)

Tags: sql, sql-server, row

Using Sql Server:
I would like to find where this ID (`MrHCClaim_id`) is in this set of criteria, but does not fall into any other criteria.  Basically find the ID's that have only one row of data.

I have tried:

```
select MrHcClaim_id, HospCd, PyrNm, payor, PatNo, SvDate, 
   sum(case when HcPcS in ('99211', '99212', '99213', '99214', '99215')
                 and SvMod like '%25%' 
            then cast(units as decimal) else 0 end) as "E&M25s", 
   sum(cast (units as decimal)) as "units"

from MrHcClaim as a
   left join MrHcClaimDtl as c
     on a.MrHcClaim_id = c.MrHcClaimDtl_id

where SvDate between '11/01/2016' 
                 and '11/30/2016'
    and payor = '1'
    and (billstatus = 't' or billstatus = 'p')
    and hospcd <> 'saltzer'

group by MrHcClaim_id, HospCd, PyrNm, payor, PatNo, SvDate
having sum(case when HcPcS in ('99211', '99212', '99213', '99214', '99215')
                   and svmod like '%25%' 
                then cast(units as decimal) else 0 end) > 0 
      and sum(cast(units as decimal)) = sum(case when hcpcs in 
                  ('99211', '99212', '99213', '99214', '99215') 
      and svmod like '%25%' then units else 0 end)
```

Comment: sample data and expected output would help

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to add another condition to your HAVING clause:

```
select MrHcClaim_id, HospCd, PyrNm, payor, PatNo, SvDate, 
   sum(case when HcPcS in ('99211', '99212', '99213', '99214', '99215')
                 and SvMod like '%25%' 
            then cast(units as decimal) else 0 end) as "E&M25s", 
   sum(cast (units as decimal)) as "units"

from MrHcClaim as a
   left join MrHcClaimDtl as c
     on a.MrHcClaim_id = c.MrHcClaimDtl_id

where SvDate between '11/01/2016' 
                 and '11/30/2016'
    and payor = '1'
    and (billstatus = 't' or billstatus = 'p')
    and hospcd <> 'saltzer'

group by MrHcClaim_id, HospCd, PyrNm, payor, PatNo, SvDate
having sum(case when HcPcS in ('99211', '99212', '99213', '99214', '99215')
                   and svmod like '%25%' 
                then cast(units as decimal) else 0 end) > 0 
      and sum(cast(units as decimal)) = sum(case when hcpcs in 
                  ('99211', '99212', '99213', '99214', '99215') 
      and svmod like '%25%' then units else 0 end)
      and COUNT(DISTINCT MrHcClaim_id) = 1
```

This will give you only the results where there is only a single record with the MrHcClaim_id value.